# Can this inpaint interpolation be made faster in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, python-xarray

There is an inpaint function written in Matlab ([Inpaintn](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27994-inpaint-over-missing-data-in-1-d-2-d-3-d-nd-arrays)) using discrete cosine transforms for filling missing values in multidimensional datasets according to this paper [Garcia et. al. (2012)](https://www.biomecardio.com/publis/envirmodellsoftw12.pdf). I tried porting this code (inpaintn.m) into Python as follows,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_edt
from scipy.fft import idctn, dctn
from tqdm import tqdm

def fill_nd(data, invalid=None):
    if invalid is None: invalid = np.isnan(data)

    ind = distance_transform_edt(invalid, return_distances=False, return_indices=True)
    return data[tuple(ind)]


def InitialGuess(y, I):
    z = fill_nd(y)
    s0 = 3
    return z, s0


def idctnn(y):
    return idctn(y, norm='ortho')


def dctnn(y):
    return dctn(y, norm='ortho')


def inpaint(xx, y0=[], n=100, m=2, verbose=False):
    x = xx.copy() #as it changes x itself, so copying it to another variable.

    sizx = np.shape(x)
    d = np.ndim(x)
    Lambda = np.zeros(sizx, dtype='float')

    for i in range(0, d):
        siz0 = np.ones(d, dtype='int')
        siz0[i] = sizx[i]
        Lambda = Lambda + np.cos(np.pi * np.reshape(np.arange(1, sizx[i] + 0.1) - 1, siz0) / sizx[i])

    Lambda = 2 * (d - Lambda)

    # Initial condition
    W = np.isfinite(x)
    if len(y0) == len(x):
        y = y0
        s0 = 3  # note: s = 10 ^ s0
    else:
        if np.any(~W):
            if verbose: print('Initial Guess as Nearest Neighbors')
            y, s0 = InitialGuess(x, np.isfinite(x).astype('bool'))
        else:
            y = x
            s0 = 3
            # return x
    x[~W] = 0.

    # Smoothness parameters: from high to negligible
    s = np.logspace(s0, -6, n)

    RF = 2.  # Relaxation Factor
    Lambda = Lambda ** m

    if verbose: print('Inpainting .......')

    for i in tqdm(range(n)):
        Gamma = 1. / (1 + s[i] * Lambda)
        y = RF * idctnn(Gamma * dctnn((W * (x - y)) + y)) + (1 - RF) * y
        
    y[W] = x[W]

    return y
```

The code works fine, but I have been trying to find ways to make this code run faster especially since my datasets are large. The advantage of using this type of interpolation is that I can feed an entire 3D dataset (with time and grid coordinates) to fill the missing values, instead of doing it for each time coordinate.

Here is an example dataset using the python

```
import numpy as np

#A 3D dataset with dimensions (time, latitude, longitude)
X = np.random.randn(1000,180,360)

# Randomly choosing indices to insert 64800 NaN values (say). 
#NaNs can also be present as blocks in the data, not randomly dispersed as below.
index_nan = np.random.choice(X.size, 64800, replace=False)

#Inserting NaNs. 
X.ravel()[index_nan] = np.nan
```

I have tried some ways but they weren't successful,

1. Using Numba

The jit decorator made it slower, even with options like `parallel/fastmath/vectorize,nopython=True` .

2. Using Cython

I tried typesetting all variables used in these functions but it was still slower than native python implementation. And moreso, it is hassle compiling Cython code on my machine.

3. Using Numpy Vectorization

I have already replaced the discrete cosine transform functions and its inverse with `scipy` functions, but I cannot seem to think of ways to vectorize the inner for loops to make it fast, and whether it is even possible.
I have tried profiling my code, and the bottleneck seems to be in the discrete cosine transforms using `scipy`. There are other bottlenecks but it doesn't make sense to me. I have attached an image for the profiling as well.
[image: INPAINT profile]

It would really help a lot if there are feasible ways to speed up this code. I am not really advanced in Python, but there is a lot that I can learn from this, especially the feasibility of my question.

Comment: Can you provide a realistic input, or if not, a random one with the exact type/shape?

Comment: I have added an example dataset in the question above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm works on a quite big array (not fitting in CPU caches) explaining partially why it is a bit slow. Moreover, DCT/IDCT are known to be expensive operations. That being said, you can parallelize the algorithm by using the Numba's JIT and the `workers=-1` option for scipy functions. Moreover, you can avoid the creation of many expensive temporary arrays by working in-place. Here is the *untested* resulting code:

```py
# In-place computation
def idctnn(y):
    return idctn(y, norm='ortho', workers=-1, overwrite_x=True)


# In-place computation
def dctnn(y):
    return dctn(y, norm='ortho', workers=-1, overwrite_x=True)


# In-place computation (writes in `Transformed`)
@nb.njit('void(float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1], float64)', parallel=True)
def ComputeGammaTransform(Transformed, Lambda, sVal):
    for i in nb.prange(Transformed.shape[0]):
        for j in range(Transformed.shape[1]):
            for k in range(Transformed.shape[2]):
                Transformed[i, j, k] /= (1. + sVal * Lambda[i, j, k])


# Out-of-place computation (writes in `out`)
@nb.njit('void(float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1], boolean[:,:,::1])', parallel=True)
def ComputeDctInput(out, x, y, W):
    for i in nb.prange(out.shape[0]):
        for j in range(out.shape[1]):
            for k in range(out.shape[2]):
                out[i, j, k] = W[i, j, k] * (x[i, j, k] - y[i, j, k]) + y[i, j, k]


# In-place computation (writes in `y`)
@nb.njit('void(float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1], float64)', parallel=True)
def ComputeDctOutput(dctResult, y, RF):
    for i in nb.prange(y.shape[0]):
        for j in range(y.shape[1]):
            for k in range(y.shape[2]):
                y[i, j, k] = RF * dctResult[i, j, k] + (1.0 - RF) * y[i, j, k]


def ComputeSteps(Lambda, x, y, W, s, RF):
    dctData = np.empty(Lambda.shape, dtype=Lambda.dtype)
    for i in tqdm(range(s.shape[0])):
        ComputeDctInput(dctData, x, y, W)
        dctnn(dctData)
        ComputeGammaTransform(dctData, Lambda, s[i])
        idctnn(dctData)
        ComputeDctOutput(dctData, y, RF)
```

This code is **5 times faster** on my machine. You can speed it up even further using simple-precision rather than double-precision. This makes the final code **7.5 times faster** than the original one on my machine.

I may be possible to speed up the code even more with GPU-based computations. The hard part is to find a GPU implementation of the DCT/IDCT in Python supporting the orthogonal normalization.

Answer (score 1):

Might be quite late, but in case somebody drops here as I did at some point.

I implemented the same algorithm, based on the original smoothn(x) code proposed by [Garcia (2010)](https://www.biomecardio.com/publis/csda10.pdf). I made a quick test against your code, and mine ended up being roughly **3.6 times faster**. Since I'm not using Numba, I guess it could be still improved a lot, as suggested by [Jérôme Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68337130). I also noticed that adding the workers option to Scipy functions slowed the algorithm in the small test I did (not generalizable for all cases).

I uploaded my code to this [repository](https://github.com/SanParraguez/smoothn/tree/main) with both the smoothing and the inpaint functions.

I made the test using the following data, which is similar but of course not the same:

```py
import numpy as np
import smoothn  # downloaded from repository

X = np.random.randn(10,180,360)

# Randomly choosing indices to insert 648 NaN values. 
index_nan = np.random.choice(X.size, 648, replace=False)
X.ravel()[index_nan] = np.nan

# Perform inpainting
Y = smoothn.inpaintn(X, max_size=-1, workers=1)
# Y = inpaint(X)
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks Santi for the update. Your attempt looks much better than what I tried.